# fopen crashes only when running from release executable

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I make several calls to a function that reads data from an input file.  Everything works fine in debug mode, but when I try to run the executable from release mode, the line with fopen crashes the program after a few calls.  My code is:
From header file:

```
#define presstankdatabase "presst_database.txt"
```

In function:

```
FILE *fidread;

fidread = fopen(presstankdatabase,"r");
if (fidread==NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open pressurant tank database: %s\n",presstankdatabase);
    return 1;
}
```

In debugging, I've inserted comment lines just before and just after the line starting with fidread =, and after several calls the program crashes and I get the message "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."  The comment just before the fopen call is displayed, but the comment just after does not.  My understanding of fopen is that is should return either a pointer or NULL, but it crashes before it even gets to the check.  The only thing I can think of is that somehow I'm having memory problems, but I don't know how that would fit in with fopen crashing.  Does anyone know what might be going on?  Thanks!

EDIT 1: I increased the size of three variables, and the only places they're used (except in printf() calls), are as shown below.

```
char *constid = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

Used like so:

```
strcpy(constid,"Propellant");
strcpy(constid,"Propellant tank");
strcpy(constid,"Pressurant tank");
```

If the variables are sized to 20, as shown above, it crashes.  But if they're larger (I've tried 120 and 100), the program runs.  The variables aren't used in any other places other than fprintf() or printf() calls.

Comment: You probably have some other problem in your code and the problem you are seeing is just a side effect of this. Try running under valgrind.

Comment: @Paul R: No such thing as valgrind in Windows, unfortunately. VC has a source-based memory debugging facility, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presstankdatabase` should be a pointer to a string containing the filename to open. If `fopen()` crashes then that pointer is probably invalid (or NULL). Without any more code it is not possible to debug it further. Use the VC debugger to see what's happening...

EDIT:

Another common cause of this is a filename string that suddenly stops being NULL-terminated.

You should add a `printf()` call to print the filename before opening. It will most probably fail to produce the expected output. If not, then you have a more interesting form of memory corruption that will take some more work to weed out.

EDIT 2:

If the `printf()` call shows the correct string, then you probably have memory corruption somewhere else in your code that has mangled some internal structure of the C library. A common cause is going beyond the end (or the beginning for that matter) of a static array or a region provided by `malloc()`.

Comment: A call to printf() produces the correct string (I used %sxxx, using xxx to make sure there are no trailing white spaces). Do you have any suggestions on what kind of memory corruption it could be?  I'm investigating the debugger, but I don't know how to use it right now.  I've always debugged my programs by inserting comments.

Comment: The call to this function with FILE *fidwrite is inside a loop. Before this loop, I open another file to write to as the loop is running (FILE *fidwritediag). Could having two files open at the same time, with one inside a loop (actually, it's a nest of three loops), have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Jade: See my edit. Try adding a large-ish amount of extra memory to all your malloc calls. If that fixes the issue, you have a start at tracking down the problem.

Comment: @thkala: So I have three variables that if I enlarge, the program runs.  However, I don't see why.  Looking at my edit, is there anything that stands out?

Comment: @Jade: The strcpy calls seem fine - unless those strings are larger than they look (e.g. because of a text editor in UTF-16 mode). 1. What if the malloc size is about 35? 2. Changing those sizes could shift the location of the actual memory corruption enough that fopen is not affected - you would still have an issue in that case. Any array accesses that may go out of bounds?

Comment: @thkala: They can be as small as 25.  Out of bounds array accesses was my first thought, but I can't find anything that seems to be going out of bounds that is close to the problem; although seeing as though it's apparently a memory issue I'm going to look through the entire program and all array accesses to make sure. Thanks for your help!